# Images in HTML email bunched together

Tags: html

I have a HTML email that displays fine in gmail and ok in outlook, except for 4 images/icons that it bunches together with no space inbetween. The code causing the issue is:

```
<tr style="height: 60px;width: 100%;background-color: #ff8000;margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <td style="border-radius:15px;"><span style="display: inline-block;float: left;font-size: 13px;padding-left: 20px;font-family: arial, sans-serif, 'Century Gothic';text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.123.com/" style="text-decoration: none;">123</a></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;float: left;font-size: 13px;padding-left: 10px;font-family: arial, sans-serif, 'Century Gothic';text-align:center;">|</span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;float: left;font-size: 13px;padding-left: 10px;font-family: arial, sans-serif, 'Century Gothic';text-align:center;"><a href="http://www.123.com/shop" style="text-decoration: none;">Shop</a></span>

        <p>
        <span style=" display: inline-block;float: right;padding-right: 40px;"><a href="https://plus.google.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/googleplus.png" title="googleplus"/></a></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;float: right;padding-right: 40px;"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/linkedin.png" title="linkedin" /></a></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;float: right;padding-right: 40px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/facebook.png" title="facebook"/></a></span>
        <span style="display: inline-block;float: right;padding-right: 40px;"><a href="https://www.twitter.com/" style="text-decoration: none;"><img src="https://storage.blob.core.windows.net/twitter.png" title="twitter"/></a></span>                
    </p>
</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: can you please either post up the complete table + css, or reference a jsFiddle? I can't see how this works in it's current form. Oh, and the image URLs are broken.

Comment: ok the use of &nbsp; after </span> has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rule to manually control whitespace:

```
white-space:pre
```

Then add spaces using the spacebar.